# SQL: How can I get from grouped table also one first row from each group

Tags: sql-server

I have following table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [DateOf] [nvarchar](20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and date as:

```
ID|Name|DateOf
1|A|2016-11-29 00:01:00
2|A|2016-11-29 00:02:00
3|A|2016-11-29 00:03:00
4|B|2016-11-29 00:01:00
5|B|2016-11-29 00:02:00
```

If I make like

```
select name, COUNT(name) from Table_1 group by Name
```

I'll have

```
A|3
B|2
```

So, how to get result like before with only one row taken from each group and sorted?

```
A|3|2016-11-29 00:01:00
B|2|2016-11-29 00:01:00
```

where last column will be sorted as date time (right now is nvarchar)

Comment: Never store dates/timestamps in varchar. Use proper data types!

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Perhaps SQL Server?)

Comment: Yeah, that's MS SQL Express 2008 R2, and column DateOf was designed before my coding :(

Comment: **AFTER** you changed the type of `DateOf`, try to combine `MAX(DateOf)` into your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.Name,A.[COUNT],MIN(DateOf)
FROM Your_table_Name T1
JOIN 
(
 SELECT COUNT(*) [COUNT],T2.Name [Name]
 FROM Your_table_Name T2
 GROUP BY T2.Name
 )A ON A.Name = T1.Name
GROUP BY T1.Name,A.[COUNT]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE and the ranking function PARTITION BY

```
            WITH CTE AS
            (          select name, dateof,
                       rn = row_number() over (partition by NAME order by dateof desc)
                       from Table_1 
            )
            SELECT name, dateof  FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Or

```
            select * from (
            select name, dateof, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by NAME order by dateof desc) as rnk 
            from Table_1 
             ) a where rnk=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
select t1.name, t1.[Count], t2.MinDate
from (
    select name, count(*) as [Count]
    from Table_1
    group by name
) AS t1
cross apply (
    select min(DateOf) as MinDate
    from Table_1 t2
    where t1.Name = t2.Name
) as t2
```

If you want to get additional data than just the min date from the row, you can modify the subselect:

```
select t1.name, t1.[Count], t2.MinDate, t2.ID
from (
    select name, count(*) as [Count]
    from Table_1
    group by name
) AS t1
cross apply (
    select top 1 DateOf as MinDate, ID
    from Table_1 t2
    where t1.Name = t2.Name
    order by DateOf
) as t2
```

Comment: Thank you :) that was exactly what I've looked from. I marked them as feedback, but can't be displayed. Thank you, once more!

Comment: If the answer (or any other of the given answers) solved your problem, you can accept it.

Comment: And is one thing more. Can I have instead of Name as letters, the numbers from 001 to 999, and I will look on results as above, and as count will be 0 (if empty) beside of each number. Exactly in situation than for ex. if record with number for ex. 234 does not exist?